# Why can't I snap curves vertices to vertices?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, snapping

Widgets with help of which you deforming curve became orange instead of red. And magnet is on and mode is set to vertices. But vertices can't be snapped to each other.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have "Project onto Self" enabled in the Snapping menu?

Comment: @Merlin doesn't help.

Comment: @Jan Kadeřábek I do, should it be enabled ?

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots done

Comment: @Merlin I uploaded the file.

Comment: @Jan Kadeřábek I uploaded the file.

Comment: I tried your file. I just downloaded and opened it and it works fine. May be it's a bug.

Comment: @FFeller it was wrong file.

Comment: @FFeller just uploaded a new one.

Comment: @Jan Kadeřábek it was wrong file, I uploaded a new one.

Comment: @Merlin it was wrong file, I uploaded a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the cases where some Blender feature doesn't work properly until you **Apply Scale**.

1. Select the curves
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
3. Select *Scale*

The snapping should work fine then.

[image]